# POST METHOD Local and live difference

Tags: php, post

I have a script that uses the jq ajax to post the data.

On my local server it works fine

but when i put it on an online server. i got some weird stuff

```
<?php

print_r($_POST);

//LOCAL returns
array(
'param'=>'<strong class="bold"></strong>';//correct
)


//LIVE returns
array(
'param'=>'<strong class=\"bold\"></strong>';//wrong
)

?>
```

and I don't know why it does it or how to fix it .. help pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any chance your live server is `Magic Quotes` enabled ?

details : http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php

Comment: Hmmm thnk u do you encourage that i use http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php for the `example #2` and what do I risk using this?

Comment: is to disable it ... when magic quote enabled, it will auto adding the slash

Comment: @Val: having `magic_quotes_gpc` enabled has no risk, it's just annoying. On the other hand, **relying on it** for input sanity has huge risks, because it really doesn't sanitize the input.

Comment: cool how can i disable it coz I have tried a couple things but not working. any ideas for the php.ini or htaccess

Comment: Yup, can check php.ini (update and restart your apache), should be similar configuration directive like http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc

Comment: they don't work I have tried the php.ini option the htaccess option (which shows a 505 btw)

Comment: unlikely related to .htaccess, look for `magic*` in the php.ini

Answer (score 2):

You have [magic_quotes_gpc](http://php.net/magic_quotes_gpc) enabled on your live server. Disable it, it's deprecated anyway and is pretty useless.